# Mean of max vs max of mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If I have say an $n$ collection of 10 random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_{10}$ (so an $n \times 10$ matrix of values) from some underlying distribution whether Gaussian or uniform, and I calculate $\operatorname{mean}_i$ and $\max_i$ for each row. How will the maximum of the different $\operatorname{mean}_i$ vary? How does this compare to the mean of the $\max_i$? Ie, which has greater variance the maximum of the mean of observations or the mean of the maximum?

Intuitively, I think mean of maximum has greater variance. This is because for the max of the mean, we apply the mean first and this averaging has a lower variance than the max.

Comment: If you use \$X_{10}\$, the $0$ will be included in the subscript.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a collection of $N \times 10$ samples from discrete distributions where the 10 max's are all the same, but the other values can be anything (i.e. $N$ is large enough so that with very high probability, the max of each of the 10 distributions is achieved by some sample and the max is equal across the 10 distributions). So then the empirical variance of the mean of max would be zero (and the theoretical variance would be very close to zero), but the variance of the max of mean could be anything, just by scaling the 10 variables to increase the variance in each distribution (thus increasing the variance of each empirical mean, even if the theoretical means of the 10 distributions are all equal).